# Can we store a deployed contract address in Remix Solidity IDE?

Tags: contract-design, contract-deployment

Suppose I need to use deployed addresses of three different contracts in any other program, then every time I need to copy the address from previous deployed contract and paste it, so is there any alternative to avoid copying and pasting the deployed unique address?

Answer (score 2):

No.

As soon as you close the window or reload it, it's all gone. But that would make a nice feature, why not write a [feature request](https://github.com/ethereum/remix-ide/issues) for it?